# What connective is missing in the following set of statements?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Like here I have, say four statements which are related to same domain. They are P, Q, R and S and following set of logic is like this: (from some definition) P implies Q (from another definition) {P implies R which implies S} (These two statements in braces are interconnected) And then somehow Q implies S

My question is exactly how Q implied S. Aren't they both supposed to be equivalent like in = How Q is connected to S? what logic is applied here?

Here is the link of same question I have asked on meta. Reason for posting it on meta was that it's a crucial doubt and I'm missing something self evident logic here. 
[What connective is missing in the following set of statements?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28095/what-connective-is-missing-in-the-following-set-of-statements) As I have only 6 reps, I can't add pictures it's in meta section where I've added an image of it.

Comment: Quite impossible to understand: please write the formulas and try to be more explicit about the problem you are asking for.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28095/what-connective-is-missing-in-the-following-set-of-statements here I have added picture too for that specific question.

Comment: If you are asking if $P \to Q$ and $P \to (R \to S)$ imply $Q \to S$, the answer is **NO**.

Comment: Then what does it imply. Is Q implied S not the correct deduction here?

Comment: A quick look at the meta question reveals that the image is just photographed text. You certainly have the reputation required to type text here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From premises:

$P \rightarrow Q$

$P \rightarrow R$

$R \rightarrow S$

it is indeed impossible to derive $Q \rightarrow S$

Part of the problem is that your $P$ and $Q$ are both referring to two atomic statements ... and you are 'losing' that fact by just using $P$ and $Q$

So, if you want to stick to propositional logic, I would symbolize something like $(a,b) \in R$ as an atomic statement in and of itself.  That is, you could use:

$A$:  $(a,b) \in R$

$B$: $(b,c) \in R$

$C$: $(b,a) \in R^{-1}$

$D$: $(c,b) \in R^{-1}$

$E$: $(a,c) \in R$

$F$: $(c,a) \in R^{-1}$

OK, so now you could represent your premises:

$A \land B$

$A \rightarrow C$

$B \rightarrow D$

$(A \land B) \rightarrow E$

$E \rightarrow F$

And the goal:

$(C \land D) \rightarrow F$

OK, but note that with this, you *still* cannot derive the conclusion.

And that is because the main problem with your proof is that as it is currently written, your written proof lacks the required flow. That is: you need to show that if $(b,a) \in R^{-1}$ and $(c,b) \in R^{-1}$, then $(c,a) \in R^{-1}$ (I assume you were asked to show that if $R$ is transitive, then $R^{-1}$ is transitive as well)

OK, so you should *start* with $(b,a) \in R^{-1}$ and $(c,b) \in R^{-1}$, then *infer* that $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$, then use transitivity of $R$ to get $(a,c) \in R$, and from that you finally get $(c,a) \in R^{-1}$.

So, what do you need to do? Well, what you really have is that in general, $(x,y) \in R$ *if and only if* $(b,a) \in R^{-1}$.  And so, you should really represent your givens as:

$A \land B$

$A \leftrightarrow C$

$B \leftrightarrow D$

$(A \land B) \rightarrow E$

$E \leftrightarrow F$

And now the goal:

$(C \land D) \rightarrow F$

is certainly derivable from those premises.

But I think the *best* way to do this proof logically, is by using first-order logic representations. As such, we are given that:

$\forall x \forall y (R(x,y) \leftrightarrow R^{-1}(y,x))$ (definition $R^{-1}$ as inverse of $R$)

and

$\forall x \forall y \forall z((R(x,y) \land R(y,z) \rightarrow R(x,z))$ ($R$ is transitive)

and the goal is:

$\forall x \forall y \forall z((R^{-1}(x,y) \land R^{-1}(y,z) \rightarrow R^{-1}(x,z))$ ($R^{-1}$ is transitive)

And here's a proof for that:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it was more to do with wrong flow of Proof from my side.

Comment: @Manny46 OK, I'm glad you realized that. Proof organization is very important! I just added a proof in first-order logic that also shows the core flow propositionally.

Comment: Thanks for that. But eventually it's if and only if condition for inverse relations not $ \to $ . Is it correct to say?

Comment: @Manny46 Correct.  And you really need that two-way connection for your proof.

Comment: Thanks but how do I make it as a habit to do required manipulation or changes for reaching to that goal? Do you have any text which can help me with that sort of manipulation as I'm self studying and not in contact with any math prof who can help me with this sort of stuffs.

Comment: @Manny46 Here's a good book that's easy enough for self-study: "How to Prove it" by Velleman

Comment: Thanks I've looked it online. It looks quite relevant for this. I'll buy it soon.

Comment: @Manny46 Yeah, lots of people like it.   Also, since you're new to Math.SE: it is customary to accept an answer if it answers your question to your satisfaction by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Comment: ticked on it. Will take care of it from now on.

Comment: @Manny46 Cool. Keep visiting this site; you can learn a lot here!

Answer (score 1):

> My question is exactly how Q implied S.

Unless there's some additional logical statements that you didn't tell, it doesn't.

Counterexample:

- $P$ is the statement “$n=2$”.
- $Q$ is the statement “$n$ is an even number”.
- $R$ is the statement “$n$ is a prime number”.
- $S$ is the statement “$n$ is not a perfect square”.

Now from the definition of even numbers, you get $P\implies Q$ ($2$ is an even number).

From the definition of prime numbers you get $P\implies R\implies S$ ($2$ is a prime, and a prime is never a perfect square).

However $Q\implies S$ would be “An even number is not a perfect square“ which clearly is false, as proved by the counterexample $4$.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28095/what-connective-is-missing-in-the-following-set-of-statements How here they've proved that R (inverse) is transitive. I think it's same pattern of statements here.

Answer (score 0):

The logic applied from these kind of questions come from [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table), and you use them to form a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)).

Edit: Your link to meta looks like you're trying to form something called an equivalence relation, you're better off reframing your question and giving the equivalence relation and showing what steps you took to establish the reflexive, symmetric, and transitive properties.